# Using Jquery Datables with MVC web api, getting 404 error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, asp.net-web-api

When I tried to call my web-api from Jquery Datatables, I got a 404 Not Found exception:

My Request URL:

```
http://someurl/API/LeaveRequest?sEcho=1&iColumns=13&sColumns=FirstName%2CFirstName%2CLastName%2CContactTypeDesc%2CTitle%2CPhone%2CEmail%2CFirstName%2CFirstName%2CLastName%2CContactTypeDesc%2CTitle%2CEmail&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&mDataProp_5=5&mDataProp_6=6&mDataProp_7=7&mDataProp_8=8&mDataProp_9=9&mDataProp_10=10&mDataProp_11=11&mDataProp_12=12&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=true&bSortable_6=true&bSortable_7=true&bSortable_8=true&bSortable_9=true&bSortable_10=true&bSortable_11=true&bSortable_12=true&userId=0
```

When I put the url into the browser, I got "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"?

I tried a simple Get call with one parameter:

```
http://someurl/API/LeaveRequest/1
```

I have no issues with this. But not sure how to format multiple parameters from datatables.

My client Code is as follows:

```
 function DisplayLeaveRequests() {
        var oTable = $('#leaveList').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/API/LeaveRequest",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "GET", 
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback,
                    "error": handleAjaxException // this sets up jQuery to give me errors
                });

            },
            "oLanguage": { "sZeroRecords": "No requests available", "sEmptyTable": "No requests available" },
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "userId", "value": 0 }
                );
            },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "FirstName" },
                        { "sName": "FirstName" },
                        { "sName": "LastName" },
                        { "sName": "ContactTypeDesc" },
                        { "sName": "Title" },
                        { "sName": "Phone" },
                        { "sName": "Email" },
                        { "sName": "FirstName" },
                        { "sName": "FirstName" },
                        { "sName": "LastName" },
                        { "sName": "ContactTypeDesc" },
                        { "sName": "Title" },
                        { "sName": "Email" }
                    ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });
    }
```

My web api (LeaveRequestController.cs) code:

```
public class LeaveRequestController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public string Get(int? iDisplayStart,
                                  int iDisplayLength,
                                  string sSearch,
                                  string filterColumn,
                                  string filterSelection,
                                  bool bEscapeRegex,
                                  int iColumns,
                                  int iSortingCols,
                                  int iSortCol_0,
                                  string sSortDir_0,
                                  int sEcho,
                                  int userId)
        {
            RequestRepository rep = new RequestRepository();
            IEnumerable<LeaveRequest> requests = rep.Get().ToList();

            var json = from a in requests
                       select ConvertProperty.Convert(new
                       {
                            a.LeaveID,
                            a.FirstName,
                            a.LastName,
                            a.EOD,
             ....etc.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to created object to all my parameters, example:

The param object:

```
public class jQueryDataTableParamModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable,
        /// same value must be returned in response
        /// </summary>       
        public string sEcho { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Text used for filtering
        /// </summary>
        public string sSearch { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of records that should be shown in table
        /// </summary>
        public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }
```

Using param object in the Get method:

```
 // GET api/<controller>
        public string Get(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
        {
```